# Ubuntu 14.04 is not showing my existing Windows 8.1 partitions

Tags: ubuntu, hard-drive, windows-8.1, partitioning

I am trying to install Ubuntu 14.04 alongside Windows 8.1. My hard disk drive has three partitions, but they are not recognized by the installer:

[image]

What should I do to Install Ubuntu alongside the preinstalled Windows 8.1? 
please can any one provide me step by step procedure to complete installation

Answer (score 0):

you can always use windows ubuntu installer, which is `wubi.exe` in ubuntu disk.
you can remove it just by uninstalling it from control panel, in case you did not like it.

Comment: What are you saying man.. Y  I did not  like it ?

Comment: i am just saying in case you did not like your 'ubuntu' setup or you want to change the setup